# Multiple matrix with vector in keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to calculate the dot product between each row of a matrix and a vector in Keras.

For example,

```
x = [[2,3,4,5,5],
     [3,4,5,6,1],
     [5,6,4,2,4],
     [4,2,3,4,1]]

w = [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.6]
```

In numpy I can just do it like this

```
[np.dot(xx, w) for xx in x]
```

But how can I do it in Keras?

P.S. I simplified the representation, I actually want to calculate the attention between one sentence with another word. So in above matrix, each number corresponds to a 300 dimension vector, since they are the same dimension, I just use one word to represent them.

I also asked the question here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4680 But nobody answered my question there, could anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How to implement `for`: I recommend you to use `K.tile` or use the `timedistributed` layer if you are not familiar with `tile`. You can image that each row is a time slice.
2. How to implement `dot`: you can define a `Dense` layer and then use `l.set_weight()` and `l.trainable=False` to fix your attention.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is marvelous!